# Why does my last <li> element hides with overflow: hidden;?

Tags: html, css

When does the last `<li>` has both float and overflow property, but still hides?

You can delete the float or the float property to see the effect.

**i want to know why the 4 element is hidden, the 5 element is shown;**

```css
.menu {
  width: 300px;
  line-height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
}  
.menu li {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
 <li style="width: 50%; background: red;">1</li>
 <li style="width: 50%; background: blue;">2</li>
    <!-- when the last one set both float and overflow it will hidden ? -->
 <li style="float: none; overflow: hidden; background: #cdf;">4</li>
    <li style="float: none; overflow: hidden; background: black;">5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Because it doesn't have width

Comment: but it has 4 text in element！

Comment: Yes, and your overflow (text) is hidden.

Comment: Why you used overflow:hidden???

Comment: @kelen Can you please provide an screenshot that how the UI should look like?

Comment: what you want realy

Comment: @aavrug you can run the code snippet to see the ui, to see the picture you can't see anything strange

Comment: @kelen Yea I am getting it but I am asking what you expecting, If you can show us then someone can suggest some alternative?

Comment: Please see my new edits below, I think they can help. Let us know.

Comment: @Stratboy thanks your answer，but i just want to know why it can hide with float none and overflow hidden.

Comment: @aavrug i want to know the  float none and overflow hidden property how it can hide the last li.

Comment: @aavrug the overflow hidden is set to li,not set to ul, if set float none only it will display block, but set overflow hidden it will hidden? why ?

Comment: @Yuri please run my new code snippet, if it doesn't has width, the 5 element why can show, the 4 element is hidden.

Comment: Because you removed the float with 4th element, then the next element will display normally.......I really don't understand what do you want to obatin. Please edit your post with actual behaviour and expected result, since your english is not that comprehensible..

Comment: Maybe this fiddle can help you https://jsfiddle.net/pu3vp9qz/

Answer (score 0):

you don't have enough space for last because you have given 50% width for first 2 li so no space remain for last one, if you want to show last one then you need to make width of 33.3333% instead of 50%

Comment: The list item would simply be placed below the current list items.

Comment: Then remove float:none from last li and add overflow:hidden on .menu class

Answer (score 0):

was set "width: 50%"  and the third element don't have free place.

```
.menu {
  width: 300px;
  line-height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
}       
.menu li {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
}

<ul class="menu">
    <li style="width: 40%; background: red;">1</li>
    <li style="width: 40%; background: blue;">2</li>
    <!-- when the last one set both float and overflow it will hidden ? -->
    <li style="float: none; overflow: hidden; background: #cdf;">4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have add 50% width for 1st both `li` tags there is no space for 3rd one I just add 33.33% for 1st and 2nd li tag and its done.

**Check below demo link in this way you can show 3rd one**

https://fiddle.jshell.net/v11wtky1/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want this?

Anyway, the main problem is that since thery're 50% width, the first 2 LI are going to fullfill the entire available space. Also, IF you'd like the last one on a new line, the right rule is `clear:both`, not `float: none`.
The overflow hidden should not play any important rule, you can keep it if you really need it.

```css
.menu {
  width: 300px;
  line-height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
}  

.menu:before,
.menu:after{ /* optional, just to give volume (clearfix) */
   content:""; display:table;
}

.menu:after{ /* optional, just to give volume (clearfix) */
  clear:both
}

.menu li {
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
}

.menu li:not(:last-child){
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  background-color:#f00;
}

.menu li:last-child {
  clear:both;
  overflow: hidden; /* no problem with overflow hidden */
  width: 100%;
  background-color:#0f0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
 <li>1</li>
 <li>2</li>
 <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks, but my goal is  want to know why the last one  can display none and has 0 width！

Comment: But is the layout you want to achieve the one I coded above? I mean, the final result. Please see my edits.